# c TCP rawsocket options

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

how to include TCP options 
MSS(maximum segment size),
WS(window scale),
sack-permitted.
options in c raw socket

we can include other options in TCP like source,destination,syn,ack
`tcp->src`,
`tcp->dst`,
`tcp->syn`,
`tcp->ack`.
.........
but when i include tcp reserverd special options mss,ws
`tcp->mss`,`tcp->ws`.
it shows an error that MSS,WS   are not in the tcp header 
can anyone show me how to include those options in tcp raw socket

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TCP WS in Linux

Assuming Linux, I believe you cannot **directly** change the TCP window size in C. This is because this is handled directly by the kernel.

One way to modify the TCP WS is to employ a mix of the following sysctl variables (read more about them in `man tcp`):

- `tcp_wmem`
- `tcp_rmem`
- `tcp_window_scaling`

According to RFC 1323 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1323.txt), TCP window scaling allows a maximum WS of 65K. The default maximum TCP WS in the Linux kernel is 32K. According to `man tcp`, you would increase the size of your socket buffer, at which point TCP Window Scaling will be used.

### TCP MSS in Linux

Once again, I believe this is only possible at the kernel level. You can override the default calculations for MSS (which are dynamically calculated based on hop distance) using the `iptables` kernel module. Specifically, using the `--set-mss` option.

See: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html

If I am wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @user It wouldn't do you much good to fiddle around with MSS or window scale even if you could, unless you magically happened to know exactly what was going on inside the kernel.